# Maya shelves and relative paths

Tags: maya, mel

Is there a way to have a relative icon and script paths for custom shelves in maya?

I want to pass on my shelf to my friend. Rather than edit the shelf each with a new path to each icon and each source, I'd rather put all the icons in a folder (named Icons) and all the scripts in a folder (named scripts) and the shelf mel file would be in the 'root' of the shelf folder. Something like:

```
SHELF_FOLDER
+-Icons
    |
    +-IconFile.bmp
+-Scripts
    |
    +-script.mel
|
--shelf.mel
```

Is there a way to set the paths at the beginning of the shelf.mel file?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a builtin way to do this, although you can explicitly call scripts from a predetermined location.

A common way to set this up is to use a [Maya module](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_130A3F57_2A5D_4E56_B066_6B86F68EEA22_htm) and then point the actual script path in the module at a network share -- that would let multiple users all load scripts and icons from a common directory knowing that they'd all have the same scripts available, and then you could include a script in that common directory to set up the shelves.

You could if you really wanted it to be modular distribute each shelf as a separate module.

Answer (score -1):

This blog post covers a lot of info regarding this:
http://rodolphe-vaillant.fr/?e=97

> Just add a .mod file in the user directory C:\Users\name\Documents\maya\version\modules. See the Maya documentation to understand this file format. The shelves won't load you will need to include a userSetup.py in your script folder (PYTHONPATH)